# Restarting containers after docker-machine host is rebooted

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, docker-machine

I am using docker-machine to manage containers on a host on DigitalOcean, as described [here (Docker documentation)](https://docs.docker.com/machine/examples/ocean/).
If my host on DigitalOcean ever reboots, I will have to manually start the containers on the remote host.

What would be a good method of restarting my containers (In the correct order) at the remote machine, while still letting me use docker-machine?

In the past I used a plain docker-engine with init / systemd / upstart configuration file. This forced me to deal with ssh-ing to the remote machine.
Is there a way to get a similar effect using docker-machine?

Comment: How about setting restart policy as 'always' for containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to add `--restart always` to your `docker run` command. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart). Note that you should design your system so that the order things come up in doesn't matter.

Comment: Will my volumes survive the restart?

Comment: They did. I used --restart unless-stopped for some of my containers, and used always for others because of the bug reported [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26087)